# When testing custom devise controller get an @controller is nil Runtime:Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, devise

I had devise generate controllers for users with the console command `rails generate devise:controllers users`, and when I try to run a simple test for `registrations_controller.rb` my console outputs the error:

> RuntimeError: @controller is nil: make sure you set it in your test's
>   setup method.

I am new to devise, but everything has seemed pretty straightforward so I don't really see why this isn't working.

This is app/controllers/users/registrations_controller.rb :

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController

  # GET /resource/sign_up
  def new
    super
    @user = User.new
  end
end
```

This is config/routes.rb :

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users, controllers: { registrations: 'users/registrations'}
  devise_scope :users do
    root                'users/registrations#new'
    get "sign_up", to: "users/registrations#new"
  end
end
```

And this is test/controllers/registrations_controller_test.rb

```
require 'test_helper'


class RegistrationsControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase
include Devise::TestHelpers


    def setup 
            @user = users(:user1)
    end

    test "should get new" do
        get :new
        assert_response :success
    end
end
```

Any help you can provide is appreciated very much!

Comment: Well have you tried `@controller = RegistrationsController.new`?

Comment: Yeah, but that just returns the error "NameError: uninitialized constant RegistrationsControllerTest::RegistrationsController"

Answer (score 2):

Per the Devise docs: "If you are testing Devise internal controllers or a controller that inherits from Devise's, you need to tell Devise which mapping should be used before a request." https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#test-helpers

```
class RegistrationsControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase
  include Devise::TestHelpers

  def setup
    request.env['devise.mapping'] = Devise.mappings[:user]

    @user = users(:user1)
  end

  test "should get new" do
    get :new
    assert_response :success
  end
end
```

You may also need to prefix your test class like so:

```
class Users::RegistrationsControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase
    ...
end
```